# My while loop in ArcMap using ArcPy is not giving what I want

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, cursor, visual-studio, while

I have revised my code I am trying to get cumulative catchments from a table in arcmap using a table, I am using four fields namely  CatName(cid), Area(Load) and DS(Downstream Node) , I want the fourth column to be populated with cumulative areas but am getting incorrect results, I am using Visual Studio Code editor with Python 2.7.16 to run ArcPy in GIS

My code is as follows

```py
import arcpy
import numpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\Temp\InfraConsult\Python_GIS'
mapname = 'C:\Temp\InfraConsult\Python_GIS\subcatchments.mxd'
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mapname)
subcatchments = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[0]
tbl = arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray(subcatchments, ("CATNAME", "Area", "DS"))
nodes = {}
totals = {}
for cid, load, dsNode in tbl:
    nodes[cid] = [dsNode.rstrip(), load]
    totals[cid] = load
    print(nodes[cid])
    #print(totals[cid])

for cid, v in nodes.iteritems():
    fromNode = cid
    load = v[1]
    print(fromNode)

while True:
        dsNode = nodes[fromNode][0]
        print(dsNode)
        if dsNode == "":
            break
        totals[dsNode] += load
        fromNode = dsNode

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(subcatchments, ("CATNAME", "CumArea")) as cursor:
    for cid, accum in cursor:
        accum = totals[cid]
        cursor.updateRow((cid, accum))
        print(accum)
        
del mxd
```

I am getting these values:

```
0.124863
0.537539
0.212485
0.439349
0.249765
0.0882654
```

Which are incorrect
[image: arcMap picture]
[image]

Comment: When you create your numpy array, you feed in "Area" but you clearly show in your screen shots there is no field called Area, but you do have a "CumArea"...

Comment: You have *four* loops (one of which incorrectly indented), with no indication of which loop you think is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you that worked it is working fine now